# How to find 2 years back date

Tags: sql-server

I want to find today's date but it should be 2 years back. E.g today's date is 6/12/2010 but I want 6/12/2008. How can I do this in SQL server?

Answer (score 41):

`SELECT DATEADD(year, -2, GETDATE())`

or

`SELECT DATEADD(yy, -2, GETDATE())`

or

`SELECT DATEADD(yyyy, -2, GETDATE())`

If you want to store it as a variable:

```
DECLARE @twoYearsAgo DATETIME;

SELECT @twoYearsAgo = DATEADD(year, -2, GETDATE());
```

Answer (score 7):

`Select DateAdd(year, -2, getdate())`

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like you need the dateadd() function http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx

```
select dateadd(yy,-2,getdate())
```

gets you this instant 2 years ago

however if you want the start of the day 2 years ago you can use

```
select dateadd(dd,datepart(dd,getdate())-1,dateadd(mm,datepart(mm,getdate())-1,dateadd(yy,datepart(yy,getdate())-1902,0)))
```

I suspect there's a cleaner way of writing this but this was what first sprang to mind.

Comment: That subroutine for selecting the start of the day is actually what I'm looking for. Many thanks!