# How to get 2 years prior date from currentdate using sql query

Tags: sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find 2 years back date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366143/how-to-find-2-years-back-date)

I need to derive 2 years prior date of current date using a query in SQL Server 2008.

For ex : today's date is `2012-11-27`. I need to get the date exactly 2 years before this date in the above format (`YYYY-MM-DD`).

Please let me know if there are multiple approaches and which one would be better.

Thanks & Regards,
Alex

Comment: What about `SELECT DATEADD(YEAR, -2, GETDATE())` ? It returns a `DATETIME` - not a string - but that would be the better choice anyway!

Comment: exactly 2 years, do you mean `2010-11-27` in your case? or exactly 365 x 2 days before? (and you don't take account leap years...)

Comment: @marc_s: why don't you put your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 4):

Try;

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(Year,-2,GETDATE()), 120) AS OldDate
```

**Edit:** Output for today's date (27/11/2012) is;

```
2010-11-27
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this could work  `dateadd(year,-2,getdate())`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE Datediff(Year, Yourdate, GetDate()) = 2
```

Answer (score -1):

Try it

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(Year,-2,GETDATE()), 120) AS [2YearsBeforeDate]
```

U get the out put like

### 2yearsBeforeDate

2010-11-27

it will give your required out put